# Trigger hover on flipbox when clicking on tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, elementor

I have a main section. Under the main section I have 2 columns, one with flipbox and other with tabs. I want to trigger hover on flip box when I clicked tab2. I don't have any clue about the JS but tried few of the fiddle's I found, the closet one to what I want is http://jsfiddle.net/EZ33Y/1/ but I was not able to get it working properly.

What I am trying to achieve is to display image related to tab for e.g Tab1 displays img1 and tab2 displays img2 or trigger hover when tab2 is selected so flip image displays tab2 img2

TIA

[image: Hover flipbox when click on tab]

```
$(function(){
    $('.tabs label').click(function(){
       $('.images img').hide();
        $('#tab'+($(this).parent('li').index()+1)+'-img').show(); 
    });
});

/* HTML */

<div class="elementor-column elementor-col-33 elementor-top-column elementor-element elementor-element-fd8fa18" data-id="fd8fa18" data-element_type="column" id="tab1">
            <div class="elementor-column-wrap elementor-element-populated">
                            <div class="elementor-widget-wrap">
                        <div class="elementor-element elementor-element-d5d5298 elementor-widget elementor-widget-eael-adv-tabs" data-id="d5d5298" data-element_type="widget" data-widget_type="eael-adv-tabs.default">
                <div class="elementor-widget-container">
                    <div id="eael-advance-tabs-d5d5298" class="eael-advance-tabs eael-tabs-horizontal" data-tabid="d5d5298">
            <div class="eael-tabs-nav">
                <ul class="eael-tab-top-icon">
                                            <li class="active">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>                                                             <span class="eael-tab-title">Tab Title 1 </span>
                        </li>
                                            <li class="inactive">
                                                                <i class="fas fa-home"></i>                                                             <span class="eael-tab-title">Tab Title 2</span>
                        </li>
                                    </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="eael-tabs-content">
                
                    <div class="clearfix active">
                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, neque qui velit. Magni dolorum quidem ipsam eligendi, totam, facilis laudantium cum accusamus ullam voluptatibus commodi numquam, error, est. Ea, consequatur.                                            </div>
                
                    <div class="clearfix inactive">
                                                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Optio, neque qui velit. Magni dolorum quidem ipsam eligendi, totam, facilis laudantium cum accusamus ullam voluptatibus commodi numquam, error, est. Ea, consequatur.                                            </div>
                            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
                </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: You'll want to share your HTML/CSS code as well so people can help you out.

Comment: @cabrerahector just updated question with my html code, i am using elementor, tried to embed js but that didnt work.